# Retrieving node's information from a sensors network in Fi-Ware

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm experiencing some problems with widgets in Fi-Ware. I'm trying to show my sensors with all parameters in a map but I get nothing. The NGSI Update seems not to be working and Map Viewer can't show my entities. I've adjusted the NGSI source to `http://my_IP:my_PORT/` and the attributes as I passed them through an updateContext call to NGSI.

This is what I can see (after passing everything needed to the widget):

[image]

Please, could you give me some help here?

Answer (score 1):

This grey widget interface you are seeing happens because the widget cannot connect correctly with the NSGI context broker server. This widget is in a very basic stage so clearly this is something to improve. You can find its code in the [github repository](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-updater) where you are free to report an issue for fixing it or making a pull request.

This error happens when there is something wrong with the configuration or the server address. We have added an example mashup to [the offer](https://store.lab.fi-ware.org/offering/CoNWeT/OrionStarterKit/1.2) that shows how to use the OrionStarterKit.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that the problem is with my Orion instance. I have access to another machine (of the same type) for another project and I'm able to view all my data through this (using the same widgets). When I change the NGSI server address, these widgets don't detect any data. All the entities are created in the same way for both machines.
Could it be due to the lack of any package, any update or something?

Comment: Thus, the widget works when connected with one Orion instance but not when connected with the other... Is that correct?

Comment: Considering the Orion instance that is not working: is the service port (the one you used in the widget configuration, typically 1026) enabled in the security group? Is the instance up and running (you can check that using `curl Orion_ip:Orion_port:/version`)?

Comment: Yes, everything is running and enabled (port in the security group, REST calls answered and entries checked in mongodb through Putty...). Everything seems to be correct and running, that's why it's driving me crazy...